# How can I make only one button toggle at a time in dijit ToolBar?

Tags: toolbar, dojo

I have a toolbar with 3 toggle buttons (I used toggle because I want the effect of clicked button)

But once I click a button I want to untoggle the rest because only 1 button can be active at a time (for example , You can't zoom in AND zoom out on the same time)

How can I do it ?

```
http://77.235.53.170/split/split.htm
```

And JSFiddle example for testing :

http://jsfiddle.net/SDN2e/

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the same scenario, I used to created a customize widget like (I call it ButtonSelector):

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/form/ToggleButton",
    "put-selector/put"
], function (declare, _WidgetBase, ToggleButton, put) {


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Define a generic Button style selector
    //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    return declare([_WidgetBase], {

        valueAttr: 'value',
        labelAttr: 'label',
        titleAttr: 'title',
        data: [],
        selectedValue: null,

        postCreate: function () {

            this.inherited(arguments);

            this.containerDiv = put(this.domNode, "div.wpt-button-selector");
            this.buttons = [];

            var getClickHandler = function (_this, _item){
                return function(evt){
                    _this.setSelectedValue(_item[_this.valueAttr]);
                };    
            } ;   

            for (var index = 0; index < this.data.length; index++) {
                var item = this.data[index];

                this.buttons.push( new ToggleButton({
                    label:item[this.labelAttr] || "",
                    title:item[this.titleAttr]||"",
                    iconClass: item.iconClass,
                    checked: item[this.valueAttr] === this.selectedValue,
                    onClick:getClickHandler(this,item)
                }, put(this.containerDiv, "span")));
            }
        },

        getSelectedValue: function () {
            return this.selectedValue;
        },

        setSelectedValue: function (newValue) {
            if (this.selectedValue != newValue) {
                this.selectedValue = newValue;
                this.selectionChanged(newValue);
            }
            this.refresh();
        },

        getSelectedIndex: function () {

            for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
                if (this.data[i][this.valueAttr] === this.selectedValue) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        },

        refresh: function () {

            for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
                this.buttons[i].set("checked", 
                    this.data[i][this.valueAttr] === this.selectedValue);
            }
        },

        //please overwrite o provide really handler
        selectionChanged: function (selectedValue) {

        }
    }); // End of ButtonSelector Definition

});
```

Then you can use it like:

```
    new ButtonSelector({
        data: [{
            value: value1,  
            iconClass: img1,
            title: Title1
        }, {
            value: value2,
            iconClass: img2,
            title: Title2
        }, {
            value: value3,
            iconClass: img3,
            title: Title3
        }],
        selectionChanged: function (value) {
              // you logic to handle change
        }
    }, put(toolBar.containerNode, "div div"))
    .setSelectedValue(yourInitialvalue);
```

Comment: Hi , I've downloaded put-selector , Created new js file with your top code and before even calling the bottom code I get error once I include your JS file :
Error: multipleDefine
and than 
TypeError: _37.set is not a function in widgetbase.js

Any chance you can update this in here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/SDN2e/

Comment: This is a working customize widget in my own projects. I get used to use programming style instead of template style. You can follow my idea to create your own version. For a template version, I suggest you to get idea from [answers of another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125105/say-i-have-many-divs-and-each-div-trigger-an-event-when-clicked/19125338#19125338).

Comment: Any chance you can edit the code here : http://jsfiddle.net/qDbd5/
I've tried doing something similiar to what you linked me but the query doesn't triggered.