# say I have many divs and each div trigger an event when clicked

Tags: dojo

Dojo 1.7
say I have many divs and each div trigger an event when clicked. So when I cilck a div, dojo adds a class, say "clicked" to the div. But how can I set it so when I click another div, it removes the previous div class "clicked" and gives it to the div that I just clicked?
This is because if I clicked on one div it supposed to change its background and remove the background from the previously clicked div
Thanks!!!

Comment: You should post what you have tried so far. Questions like this really benefit from including some code, as well as putting it up on jsfiddle for people to work from. It makes it a lot easier to get help and understand what you want. Include the HTML, relevant styles, and the JS you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can put all these div in one container, for example

```
<div class='RadioDivContainer'>

  <div> </div>
  ....
  <div>  </div>

<div>
```

Then do this in onclick event handler of divs:

```
dojo.query(".RadioDivContainer .clicked").forEach(function(node){
     dojo.removeClass(node, "clicked");
}); 

dojo.addClass(evt.target, "clicked");
```

This is just show the idea how to implement it. You can change it to suit your case.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable hooks to your desired DOM elements with `dojo.query`, handle click events using `dojo.on` and assign/unassign classes with `dojo/dom-class`. Give the `div` elements a shared class to denote that they are part of this clickable unit, then listen for click events on all of them and assign classes as necessary. See this **[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NDtde/1/)**, using **Dojo 1.7.4**:

**HTML**

```
<div class="mutable"></div>
<div class="mutable"></div>
<div class="mutable"></div>
```

**Javascript/Dojo**

```
require(["dojo/query", "dojo/dom-class", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"], function(query, domClass, on) {
    on(query(".mutable"), "click", function(e) {
        query(".mutable").forEach(function(node) {
            domClass.remove(node, "clicked");
        });
        domClass.add(this, "clicked")
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.mutable {
    background-color:red;
}

.clicked {
    background-color:green;
}

div {
    border:2px solid black;
    margin:5px;

}
```

This will also work with Dojo 1.8.x and 1.9.x.

Comment: You can cache the `query` results so you're not getting the DOM elements twice, or on each click. Of course, if you dynamically add an element, you'd have to re-run the query, but that can be easily implemented.

Comment: This is true. If there aren't a gazillion or so DOM elements to parse, this is still a *relatively* inexpensive and maintainable approach, though there's nothing wrong with caching. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `clicked` class from all the elements in the group before applying the `clicked` class to the newly-clicked element.

Using Dojo 1.7:

```
require([
    'dojo/query',
    'dojo/dom-class',
    'dojo/on',
    'dojo/dom',
    'dojo/domReady!'
], function(query, dom_class, on, dom) {
    var boxes = query('.box', dom.byId('#container')); // get elements inside #container
    boxes.forEach(function(box) {
        on(box, 'click', function() {
            boxes.forEach(function(b) {
               dom_class.remove(b, 'clicked'); 
            });
            dom_class.add(box, 'clicked');
        });
    });
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/m7veF/).

You could also keep track of the last clicked element and remove the `clicked` class from that. You can see both examples in the fiddle.