# Dojo on query click doesn't work in toolbar on toggle button

Tags: toolbar, dojo

Following the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125105/say-i-have-many-divs-and-each-div-trigger-an-event-when-clicked/19125338#19125338) I've tried doing the same but the query doesnt work for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/qDbd5/

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/Toolbar", "dijit/form/ToggleButton", "dojo/query", "dojo/dom-class", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"], function (parser, ToolBar, ToggleButton, query, domClass, on) {
on(query(".dijitToggleButton"), "click", function (e) {
    query(".dijitToggleButton").forEach(function (node) {
        console.log('Captured clicked event');
        domClass.remove(node, "dijitToggleButtonChecked dijitToggleButtonRtlChecked dijitRtlChecked dijitChecked");
    });
    domClass.add(this, "dijitToggleButtonChecked dijitToggleButtonRtlChecked dijitRtlChecked dijitChecked");
});
```

});

I'm trying to make only 1 button toggle at a time.
Why the click event not triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping everything in a ready() callback solves the problem.

See http://jsfiddle.net/cFQGq/

```
require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/parser", "dijit/Toolbar", "dijit/form/ToggleButton", "dojo/query", "dojo/dom-class", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"], function (ready, parser, ToolBar, ToggleButton, query, domClass, on) {
    ready(function() {
        on(query(".dijitToggleButton"), "click", function (e) {
            query(".dijitToggleButton").forEach(function (node) {
                console.log('Captured clicked event');
                domClass.remove(node, "dijitToggleButtonChecked dijitToggleButtonRtlChecked dijitRtlChecked dijitChecked");
            });
            domClass.add(this, "dijitToggleButtonChecked dijitToggleButtonRtlChecked dijitRtlChecked dijitChecked");
        });
    }); 
});
```

If you look at the [explanation of domReady](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/domReady.html)!, it mentions that it is insufficient for working with dojo widgets, because it executes after the DOM has loaded instead of after the widget has finished initializing. dojo/ready executes the callback after the widgets have finished loading.

Comment: I've notcied a bug. In the JSFiddle you updated , If I click copy , than click paste and than HOVER on copy... it get the toggle style althoug I didn't click it. Any idea why ?

Comment: I've solved the bug.
Need also to set "checked=false" in the dijit item.